# Locating url of sharepoint site for file transfer

Tags: url

I have been using Sharepoint Workspace 2010 on my laptop.  In an attempt to transfer my Sharepoint documents to my iPad 3 (via Colligo Briefcase Pro application), I have to provide the url of my Sharepoint site.  As I am using Sharepoint for my personal documents, the only reference I have to a Sharepoint site is the message that appears every time I save a document - "saving to the server".

Any thoughts as to how I proceed in transferring my files to my iPad 3?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Your must amend the browser URL in order for it to authenticate properly.

There could be three reasons to this:

**1. Shortened URL**
For example, if you enter the following URL in the Add Site dialog: http://sitename.corporate.local/subsite/SitePages/Home.aspx, Briefcase is able to detect the root of the site for authentication. However, if you turn this URL into a shortened one, Briefcase is no longer able to detect the root and authentication will fail. Therefore if you want to create a shortened URL, you must amend the original URL to read as follows: http://sitename.corporate.local/subsite/

**2. Site Resolution**
iPads do not behave the same way as PCs do on a network, and as such iPads do not resolve URLs the same way as PCs. This may result in an error when adding a site to the Sites list in Briefcase.

Resolution:

The SharePoint site should have the fully qualified URL added to the access modifiers.

For example: `http://pacificfinancial/Pages` may need to be entered as `http://pacificfinancial/Pages.corporate.local`

**3.Site is not connectable**
Contributor was able to connect to a web server but the SharePoint site with the specified URL was not found on this server.

Resolution:

Ensure the site exists and that you have at least read permissions.